# How to replace duplicates in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of Books and Authors, but the database I have been given has got duplicates with Authors appearing more than once.
I would like to replace the fk_id_author in the Written table by the min(id_author) when there are duplicates.

Here are the three tables (simplified for the example):

**Author**

- id_author
- author_name

**Book**

- id_book
- book_name

**Written** (an author can write n books and a book can be written by n authors)

- fk_id_book
- fk_id_author

I have made a request to find authors that appears more than once in the Authors table with their ids and ids of the books they have written :

```
SELECT MIN w.fk_id_book, w.fk_id_author, d.author_name, d.nb_written
FROM Written_by w
JOIN (SELECT c.id_author, c.author_name, b.nb_written
FROM Author c
    JOIN (SELECT MIN(a.id_author), a.author_name, COUNT( a.author_name)
    nb_written  
        FROM Author a
        GROUP BY a.author_name
        HAVING nb_written >1) b
        ON (c.author_name = b.author_name)      
        ORDER BY c.author_name ASC) d
    ON w.fk_id_author = d.id_author)
GROUP BY w.fk_id_author
ORDER BY d.author_name ASC, w.fk_id_author ASC
```

The result is :

```
fk_id_book ; fk_id_author ; author_name  ; nb_written
80   ; 18  ; Rousseau ; 3
175  ; 127 ; Rousseau ; 3
1307 ; 150 ; Rousseau ; 3
127  ; 302 ; Voltaire ; 2
1503 ; 927 ; Voltaire ; 2
```

The problem:

I would like to get the list of fk_id_book written by an author with the same name but not the same id on the same row:

```
list of fk_id_book ; min(fk_id_author) ; author_name  ; nb_written
80,175,1307  ; 18  ; Rousseau ; 3
127,1503  ; Voltaire ; 2
```

Is it possible in MySQL?

Then with PHP, I will update Written for the list of fk_id_book 80,175,1307 with fk_id_author 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was a duplicate.
Here is the solution:

1 update the fk_id_author

```
update  written
join    author a1
on      a1.id_author = written.fk_id_author
set     written.fk_id_author = 
        (
        select  min(a2.id_author )
        from    author a2
        where   a2.author_name = a1.author_name
    )
```

2 delete authors without written entries:

```
DELETE FROM author 
WHERE id_author NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT fk_id_author 
    FROM written
)
```